# AWS S3 bucket website + cloudfront + route 53 + SSL -> www.domain.com not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've tried searching SO to find an existing thread but not much luck.

**Issue:** 
.com works, but www. x .com and https://www. x .com results in a Cloudfront error

```
The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID:
```

**The setup:**

1. S3 bucket with Enable website hosting
2. SSL cert purchased from GoDaddy and uploaded to AWS
3. Cloudfront distribution

   - referencing the SSL cert
   - Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): myDomain.com
   - Origin pointing to S3 bucket from 1.
   - Behavior: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
4. Route 53 config

   - example.com / Alias / pointing to my Cloudfront distribution
   - example.com / MX / 0 smtp.secureserver.net
   - example.com / NS / 4 records created by AWS
   - example.com / SOA / 1 record created by AWS
   - 4 records created for SES & DKIM
   - subdomain.example.com / NS / 4 referencing another Route 53 Zone for a subdomain, which is a test env with HTTPS
5. domain on GoDaddy but with custom nameserver config - 4 records pointing to the Route 53 NS config for myDomain.com

**What works** 
Pretty much everything else...

1. com routes to https .com
2. https .com
3. https subdomain

Any ideas?

I currently have a DNS record for 
www example com / A / referencing example .com

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution would be to add another A record which points to a www.x.com s3 bucket and redirect traffic from the www.x.com bucket to the root x.com.

1. In s3 in the aws console create a bucket named www.x.com
2. set up a redirect under static website hosting in the properties for the new www.x.com bucket to the plain x.com
3. in Route 53 create another A record in the x.com hosted zone
4. for the A record point www.x.com to a target of the www.x.com s3 bucket
5. wait for the record to propagate if it does not take effect immediately

I believe this is a reasonable solution to your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response Akai! To clarify... do you mean I should add a 2nd www s3 bucket?   and only have ONE alias record, which points directly to that www s3 bucket?

Comment: yes and no, you can add another bucket for www.x.com, add a redirect to x.com and add an associated A record pointing to the www bucket. You do _not_ need only one alias record because you will still need an A record for the x.com domain to point to the cloudfront distribution. I've edited my answer please take a look